# Java arraylist object to array

Tags: java, arraylist

I am creating an ArrayList of String Arrays in Java.. The code for the same is follows..

```
ArrayList<String[]> al = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for(int i = 0; i < t; i++) {  // t is input by user representing size of arraylist
    int k = sc.nextInt();
    String[] s = new String[k]; // k string values input by user
}
```

Iterating to print the values of ArrayList

```
Iterator it = al.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    for(int i = 0; i < (it.next(new String[])).length; i++) {  // error for dimension missing
        System.out.println((it.next(new String[])).length); // error for dimension missing
    }
}
```

I get an error of "array dimension missing" in the indicated lines. Please suggest how to convert ArrayList Object as String Array.

Comment: Why are you using a raw `Iterator`? You list is typed, so it should give you back a typed `Iterator`, and then you don't have to mess with casting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Iterator<String[]> it = al.iterator();

while(it.hasNext()){
String temp [] = it.next();
for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) { 
    System.out.println(temp.length);
  }
}
```

Comment: No problem! glad

Answer (score 0):

your `new String[]`
requires size, because you're making new array i.e

```
String[] myStringArray = new String[5];
```

also, your iteration to print values make no sense, try :

```
for(String[] stringArray: al) {
    System.out.println("Size: " + stringArray.length);
    for(String s: stringArray) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```